# Error in loading the file into the table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
load DATA LOCAL 
infile 'C:\Users\abcdefg.h.ABCINDIA\datafile.csv'
INTO TABLE XXSYMC.invoice_demo 
fields terminated BY "  " optionally enclosed BY '"' 
(invoice_number,org_id,supplier_id);
```

I get the error as shown below:

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer is for running SQL statements and PL/SQL code. What you're trying to run is [SQL*Loader control file syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_control_file.htm).

They are completely different tools, and you cannot run SQL*Loader commands from SQL Developer. If you want to load that file you can use the [SQL*Loader command line](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_params.htm).

If the file is available on the database server you could create [an external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) instead, and copy the data from that into your real table; you could at least do that from SQL Developer, as long as you have the right permissions and can put the file in a server directory that Oracle recognises...